# python change str to hex, NOT CONVERTING

Tags: python, hex

I'm trying to take a string and change it to hex.  I do not want to convert the string to hex just change it. for example

```
x = '13'
```

I want to change `x` to equal `0x13`.  I don't want it to be a string any longer.

Is that possible?

The long of it is I'm trying to take in a two digit number vi user input.  The user will input numbers in two digit chunks.  Those numbers will have to be changed into the hex representation, so they can be Xor'd against another hex number.

Comment: Sorry, what? `x = '0x' + x` would solve your problem, but you don't want the string to be any longer?

Comment: You can **interpret** the string as a hexadecimal number, making it an integer. Then you can XOR it too, you don't have to have hexadecimal notation for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hexadecimal is just a *representation* of a number; you could write the same number down as `23` in octal, or `00010011` in binary, or `19` in decimal, and they all would represent the same value.

To XOR two numbers, they don't need to be in any notation, you just need integers. You can interpret a string as a hexadecimal number by using the `int()` function with a base of 16:

```
x = int(x, 16)
```

Now you have an integer that you can XOR with another:

```
x ^ 255
```

would invert all the bits. Note that the default representation for Python integers is in decimal, so if you `print x` then you'll see `19` again, not `13`. To represent the number back in hexadecimal, without the `0x` prefix, use:

```
format(x, 'x')
```

where the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format), given the `x` formatter, returns the hexadecimal representation for a given integer again. `b` would give you a binary string, `o` an octal string.

Demo:

```
>>> int('13', 16)
19
>>> format(19, 'x')
'13'
>>> format(19 ^ 255, 'x')
'ec'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(x, 16)
```

This may meet your need

Answer (score 1):

You want this?

```
>>> x = "13"
>>> x = int("0x" + x, base=16)
>>> x
19
```